# About using Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I download the Microsoft Chart Controls Add-on for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
   and Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.

But can not able to see the control in toolbox of visual studio 2008.

Regards
Hrishi

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:
To install the Chart Control for .NET Framework

1. Download the installation packages for Microsoft Chart Control for .NET Framework.
2. To install the Chart control library, double-click the MSChart.exe file.
3. To install the Visual Studio add-on, double-click the MSChart_VisualStudioAddOn.exe file.
4. After installation completes, start Visual Studio 2008 and open a project.
5. In the design view, open the Toolbox.
6. From the Data section, drag a Chart control to the design area.

**If you cannot see the Chart control in the Toolbox window**, right click in the Toolbox window, select Choose Items to open the Choose Toolbox Items dialog, and then select the following namespaces in the .NET Framekwork Components tab:

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting


System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
```

Note   To find the Chart control more easily in the Toolbox, hide the inactive controls. To do this, right-click the Toolbox, and clear Show All item.